# Codeigniter Join tables get name with id

Tags: sql, codeigniter, join

I have the following tables:

---

mob:

> id, name, icon

---

example:

> 3, fox , fox.png

---

and

---

route:

> id, name, mob1, mob2, mob3, mob4, mob5, mob6, mob7, mob8

---

example:

> 1, first_route, 1, 3, 4, 7 ,2 ,4, 5 ,6

---

At the mob1,2,n,8 the vallues assigned are the IDs of different records from the mob table. (Basicaly sequance of mobs)

What I want is to get the values for mob1,2,3 ect compare them to the IDs of mob and that way to get the Name of the mob.

So in the end when I display the data I have:

ID of route, Name of route, name of mob1, name of mob2, ect

Here is the model:

```
function get_all($limit=null,$offset=null) {
            $this->db->select('route.*, mob.*');
            $this->db->from('route', 'mob');
            $this->db->join('mob', 'mob.id = route.mob1', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m1', 'm1.id = route.mob1', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m2', 'm2.id = route.mob2', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m3', 'm3.id = route.mob3', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m4', 'm4.id = route.mob4', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m5', 'm5.id = route.mob5', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m6', 'm6.id = route.mob6', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m7', 'm7.id = route.mob7', 'left');
            $this->db->join('mob AS m8', 'm8.id = route.mob8', 'left');
            $res = $this->db->get();
            return $res->result_array();
```

I am able to get the IDs of mobs, but not the names, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please could you try to change these two lines:

```
$this->db->select('route.*, mob.*');
$this->db->from('route', 'mob');
```

to

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('route');
```

Comment: Same result, I am getting the IDs and the name and icon of the last one (mob8). If I remove $this->db->join('mob AS m8', 'm8.id = route.mob8', 'left'); i am getting the info for mob7 correctly ect.